# Any change to redux store my causes component to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm doing some testing on my UI and I've noticed that **if *any* state changes in my redux store my component (shown below) re-renders and restarts with embedded video at 0.** If I type in a redux-connected text field, it remounts, if a status notification hits the store, it remounts, etc.

I have no idea how to fix this and I could really use some help figuring out how to go after the bug.

**tldr; How can I stop my VideoPlayer from re-rendering each time something changes in my redux store?**

- `redux-toolkit`
- `react`

---

##### component

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
...
// data used in the VideoPlayer is descructured from this variable:
const formState = useSelector(selectDynamicForm);

// renders output here in the same component
return (
...
 {sourceContentFound === false ? (
   <VideoPlayerDisabled />
 ) : (
   <VideoPlayerController
     title={title}
     description={description}
     sourceAddress={iframeURL}
     author={authorName}
     timeStamp={{ startTime: 0 }}
   />
 )}
)
...
}
```

##### formSlice

```
export const dynamicFormSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dynamicForm',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateField: (state, action) => {
      state = action.payload;
      return state;
    }
  },
});

export const selectDynamicForm = createSelector(
  (state: RootState): dynamicFormState => state.dynamicForm,
  dynamicForm => dynamicForm
);
```

##### statusHandlerSlice

I don't think this component does anything crazy, per-say, but I have a notification appear when the video conditions are met. When it goes back down `clearStatus` the video player restarts.

```
export const statusHandlerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'statusHandler',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setStatus: (state, action: PayloadAction<IStatusObject>) => {
      const { type, display, message } = action.payload;
      state.status = {
        ...action.payload,
        message: message.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + message.slice(1),
      };
      if (display === 'internal-only' || display === 'support-both') {
        statusLogger(type, message);
      }
    },
    clearStatus: state => {
      state.status = {
        type: 'success',
        data: {},
        message: '',
        display: 'internal-only',
        key: '',
      };
    },
  },
});

export const { setStatus, clearStatus } = statusHandlerSlice.actions;

export const selectStatus = (state: RootState): IStatusObject =>
  state.statusHandler.status;
```

Comment: If you replace formState and set it with an object: `const formState = {}` will it still re render? Maybe it's props passed from parent that causes the re render. It is not clear why formState is needed since the code in your question never uses it.

Answer (score 4):

**Your `MyComponent` is re-render every time redux store state change is because you have a selector in it**

You could stop this to happen by, add an [equalityFn](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) to `useSelector`.

You can write your own `equalityFn` or use some existing function from a library that supports deep comparison.

**Ex: Use lodash `isEqual`**

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
const MyComponent = () => {
...
// data used in the VideoPlayer is descructured from this variable:
const formState = useSelector(selectDynamicForm, isEqual);
```

---

By default, `useSelector` use a `shallow` compare which can't detect deep changes inside your object, change to a deep comparison function like `isEqual` will help you to do that, but It's not recommended for all selector since there will be a performance impact.

Live Example:

[image: Edit redux-useSelector-useDispatch-Sample (forked)]

Comment: Thank you, I've installed and added isEqual to my `useSelector` hook but the behavior is still triggering, unfortunately. I have multiple different slices all interacting with different parts of the store, any change to any of them still causes the re-render. This bug is pretty terrifying.

Comment: Is your `formState` new evey time? `isEquality` only work when your `formState` is the same object every time.

Comment: As I mentioned, You can also write your own comparison function based on your specific needs, Only re-render when there is a change that you need.

Comment: hm, the form's state isn't changing. When I select a file, it gets the information and sets it the `formSlice` state. Then, a notification appears from `statusHandlerSlice`, once it ends, it fires `clearStatus`. Both of these events are happening from another slice in RTK and neither of them change the state of `formSlice`. They only change their part of the great redux store.

Comment: I can see in the redux-devtools, as soon as the `statusHandlerSlice` dispatches an action my `VideoPlayer` refreshes. Even though the `VideoPlayer` is not dependent on any state from the `statusHandlerSlice`

Comment: I'm sure this is confusing since there are so many things going on. I'll need to strip away functionality from my component & store tomorrow and see if I can narrow down what exactly is causing this. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, You might need to do so, you can get back to my answer and try out the `equalityFn` method, I guarantee that it will work if you have a proper setup which I did in my project too.

Comment: I have the lodash isEqual in place just like in your example. Unfortunately, that didn't prevent the behavior. Perhaps my implementation has an error somewhere.

Comment: You can try to log the `formState` out to see if it's exactly the same object every time?

Comment: @kevin, Hey man, I added a small example in the answer to demonstrate the `useSelector` comparison. You can check it to have a better understanding.

Comment: Remove `isEqual` to see the `UnRelatedComp` re-render eveytime.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest either creating a custom equalFn to compare the data you're using in the current component or do not select the whole slice, maybe some properties change is unnecessary for your component. like:

```js
const { data } = useSelector(store => store.sliceA, shallowEq);

// console.log(data) => { a: "foo", b: "bar" }
// data.b is useless but once it is changed, the component will re-render as well

return <Typography>{data.a}</Typography>
```

2. You should install React Devtools, turn on profiler, remember to check `Record why each component rendered while profiling` in setting to see what is causing re-rendering. sometimes custom hooks in libraries trigger re-rendering.
3. [whyDidYouRender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render)
   is a good choice too